# How to attract white stork (Ciconia ciconia) to a garden?

Tags: birds

Is there any way to attract white stork (Ciconia ciconia) to a garden?

I found this on the internet, but without much further info: A [wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ciconia_ciconia_juv_small.jpg) photo of a man-made structure for stork's nest: (is it necessary to construct this to attract storks? is it effective?)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to build a Stork nest, you have to take a few things into consideration.

- Do Storks live in your area?
- Are there enough food and resources in the neighborhood?
- Is it possible to build a nest where the birds can freely fly into? No obstacles?

The nest is usually build on a pole of 4-6 meters, depending on obstacles in vicinity. I have seen nests which were nothing more than a pole with a old wooden cart wheel on it. Storks normally return to Europe in February, so be sure to put your nest up before that time.

Comment: The nearest stork nests are 5 km away - do you think that this rules out my place as potential stork's home?

Comment: 5 km is pretty much in your area, do you think a new family can find enough food (from meadows, riverbanks)? I think it will have a chance, but no guarantees ;)

Comment: Storks are like cats - you cant control them, choose the place where they sleep... I guess

Comment: I know people making artificial nests on seemingly perfect places - but storks didn't come.

Comment: Be aware of possible hindrance such a nest may bring. Storks can make hard noise with their beaks, and defecate around the nest. Also they may bring children to your home :P

Comment: Are you suggesting altogether different approach to attracting storks? ;)